# Актуальный Laravel пакет для прав и ролей

Tags: php, laravel

Пытался найти какой-то готовый пакет и посмотрел на популярный spatie/laravel-permission.
Всё бы хорошо, но только как правильно реализовать возможность отобрать какие-то определенные права у пользователя?

Например, отобрать у определенного пользователя права на постинг комментариев.

Тот пакет не подходит, тк там отбирать права можно только полностью у ролей. (например, тогда вся группа пользователей не сможет комментить)
https://github.com/spatie/laravel-permission/issues/655

Вот и сижу думаю, возможно я как-то неправильно архитектуру прав и ролей себе придумал? Или всё же есть такие пакеты?

Comment: Другие пакеты как будто имеют такую же проблему, а остальные без поддержки уже кучу времени..

Comment: https://spatie.be/docs/laravel-permission/v5/introduction прям на титульной странице `$user->givePermissionTo('edit articles');` и чуть далее по документации `$user->revokePermissionTo('edit articles');`

Comment: @ArchDemon, забрать можно только выданные права. Но при ситуации, когда данные права предусмотрены ролью, их ограничить у определенного пользователя не получится

Comment: Выдавайте права не через роли, а через права. Тогда их можно будет забирать. Дело в том, что доступ на то или иное действие осуществляется по наличию права в списке прав. В списке прав не может быть записи вида "запретить ..."